# Can I load a picture into mySQL server-side?

Tags: mysql, image

I need to create a simple mySQL database with a field for an image.

Is there a simple example that explains the type of field and how to upload from a directory on the server, etc...?

Thanks.

Erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example of BLOB Storage:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `files` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `filename` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ext` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `filedata` blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;

<?php
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die('Could not connect:' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('the_database',$db);

if(isset($_FILES['upload'])){

    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'])) {
        $file_parts = pathinfo($_FILES['upload']['name']);

        $file['name'] =$file_parts['filename'];
        $file['ext']  =$file_parts['extension'];
        $file['data'] =addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'])); 

        mysql_query('INSERT into files (id,filename,ext,filedata) values ("","'.$file['name'].'","'.$file['ext'].'","'.$file['data'].'")',$db) or die(mysql_error());
        $notice="File Uploaded successfully";
    }
}
?>


<html>
<head>
<title>BLOB Upload</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
<h1 align="center">BLOB Upload</h1>
  <p align="center"><input type="file" name="upload" size="40"></p>
  <p align="center"><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>
  <?php if(isset($notice)){echo '<p align="center">'.$notice.'</p>';}?>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways (at least) to store images in a database:-

1. Store a reference to a file on the filesystem
2. Store them as binary data inside the database

Binary data stored inside databases are known as BLOBS (binary large objects), you can read up more here:-

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LOAD_FILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) function to returns the file contents as a string, e.g. -

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (LOAD_FILE('img.png'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the images in folders using fwrite or php GD libary.

Then save the image path in database, possible along with additional information such as size,width,height,name etc to be able to filter/sort them.