# Problems displaying blob images

Tags: php, mysql, image, download, blob

This is my actual code, i'm starting to using php and i want to know how to display a blob image on my website.
But until now i can't find how to do it. This is my php code...

```
$query=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT image, titulo, tecnica, medidas FROM upload ");

$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

$posts = array();

if ($numrows != 0)
{
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
  {
      $post = new stdClass();
      $post->image = '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'"/>';    
      $post->titulo  = $row['titulo'];
      $post->tecnica  = $row['tecnica'];
      $post->medidas  = $row['medidas'];

      array_push($posts, $post);
   } 
   }

  $jsonData = json_encode($posts);

  header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");

  echo $jsonData;
```

Comment: Your not outputting an image, your returning json, which is fine but set the appropriate header `application/json` not `image/jpeg`, Some simple examples here: [Upload into blob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012355/can-i-load-a-picture-into-mysql-server-side/10012471#10012471) | [Display from blob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468338/i-want-to-show-image-on-php-which-is-store-in-mysql-database-as-blob-type/8468369#8468369)

Comment: thanks Loz Cherone ツ!!! thats just what i need to do to display the images!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

    //Connect to the database
  $databasehost = "YOUR DATABASE HOST";
  $databasename = "YOUR DATABASE NAME";
  $databaseusername ="YOUR DATABASE USERNAME";
  $databasepassword = "YOUR DATABASE PASSWORD";

  $con = mysqli_connect($databasehost, $databaseusername, $databasepassword, $databasename) or die(mysqli_error($con));
  mysqli_set_charset ($con, "utf8");

$sql = "SELECT image, titulo, tecnica, medidas FROM upload;";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
array_push($result,
array(
'image'=>base64_encode($row[0]),
'titulo'=>$row[1],
'tecnica'=>$row[2],
'medidas'=>$row[3]
));
}
echo json_encode(array($result));

mysqli_close($con);
```

This will print your data like this:

> {[{"image":"*IMAGE ENCODED IN BASE 64*","titulo":"*SOME
>   DATA*","tecnica":"*SOME DATA*", "medidas":"*SOME DATA*"},
>
> {"image":"*IMAGE ENCODED IN BASE 64*","titulo":"*SOME
>   DATA*","tecnica":"*SOME DATA*", "medidas":"*SOME DATA*"},
>
> {"image":"*IMAGE ENCODED IN BASE 64*","titulo":"*SOME
>   DATA*","tecnica":"*SOME DATA*", "medidas":"*SOME DATA*"}]}

Hope it helps! Good Luck! Happy Coding!